# Sql DELETE c вложенным SELECT

Tags: sql

Добрый день.
Есть таблицы

```
Semesters(Id,Name,CreatedBy) 
Groups(Id,Name,SemesterId)  //SemesterId привязан к Semesters.Id
```

Нужно удалить данные из таблицы Groups, допустим пользователь отсылает- удалить группу 1, потом надо проверить -является ли он создателем "Семестра", в котором находится данная группа и если да- то удалить .

Почему именно так? Просто если попадётся "слишком умный чувак", что б он не поотсылал на удаление айдишники тех групп, которые ему не принадлежат

Comment: делается это через запрос DELETE с объединением через JOIN другой таблицы. Вот запрос из моей базы `DELETE cs.* FROM calcs_special AS cs LEFT JOIN calcs_adds AS ca USING(specialID) WHERE ca.specialID IS NULL`

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from groups WHERE SemesterId IN 
(SELECT id FROM semesters WHERE userid=7) AND groups.id=4
```

Проверка юзера 7 , который хочет удалить группу 4